# clearInterval(timerId) is not working

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I want to start counting when on `mouseenter` event and then to stop counting on `mouseleave` event. However, as you can see in the console of this example, the `clearInterval(timerId)` command inside mouseleave is not working.

What's the problem?

```js
var timerId;
clearInterval(timerId);

$("#demo").mouseenter(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    startcounting(timerId);
  }, 2000)
});

$("#demo").mouseleave(function() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
});

function startcounting(timerId) {
  var number = 0;
  timerId = setInterval(function() {
    increment(timerId);
  }, 100);

  function increment(timerId) {
    if (number >= 100) {
      number = 0;
      clearInterval(timerId);
    } else {
      number++;
      console.log(number);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">demo</div>
```

Comment: Please note that all relevant code should be placed in the question, just in case jsFiddle goes down. If that had happened, your question would have been unanswerable.

Comment: thank you very much for you comment! I'm new here and I could never think of that if you didn't tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you've got a parameter of your `startcounting()` and `increment()` functions named `timerId` which is hiding the variable of the same name in the outer scope - which is the one you need.

If you remove those properties, the code works:

```js
var timerId;
clearInterval(timerId);

$("#demo").mouseenter(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        startcounting(); // remove here
    }, 2000)
});

$("#demo").mouseleave(function() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
});

function startcounting() { // remove here
    var number = 0;
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        increment(timerId);
    }, 100);

    function increment() { // remove here
        if (number >= 100) {
            number = 0;
            clearInterval(timerId);
        } else {
            number++;
            console.log(number);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">demo</div>
```

Comment: I have embedded the code from your answer into a snippet, as I did with the question. You may wish to review and update it, or roll back if you object to me doing this.